# Micronaut: Unable to inject a bean inside Quartz job

Tags: groovy, micronaut

I am trying to inject bean (Either data access GORM service or any other bean) in the Quartz Job implemented class, but it always shows null. Same beans (GORM or other beans) are able to inject without any issues in other classes.
can you please help me to retrieve any bean in this Job class.

My Quartz job

```
@Singleton
@Slf4j
class MyQuartzJob implements Job {

    @Inject
    MyHttpBean myHttpBean // unable to inject

    @Inject
    ApplicationContext appContext // unable to inject

    @Inject
    MyGORMService     myGormService // unable to inject
}

@Singleton
@Slf4j
class MyHttpBean {
// business logic
}
```

code to invoke QuartzJob

```
@Singleton
@Context
@Slf4j
@CompileStatic
class MasterScheduler{

     @PostConstruct
     void init(){
       // Quartz Job initialization code written here. This works fine.
     }
}
```

my build.gradle

```
dependencyManagement {
    imports {
        mavenBom 'io.micronaut:micronaut-bom:1.3.2'
    }
}

dependencies {
    annotationProcessor("io.micronaut:micronaut-inject-java:1.3.2")
    annotationProcessor("io.micronaut:micronaut-inject-groovy:1.3.2")
    implementation("io.micronaut:micronaut-inject:1.3.2")
  
    // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.quartz-scheduler/quartz
    compile group: 'org.quartz-scheduler', name: 'quartz', version: '2.3.0'

     ... other dependencies
}

Java version: 1.8
```

Note: I am using Micronaut scheduling capabilities, but I need distributed execution support & hence moving to Quartz ...

Comment: In your app, what is creating the instance of `MyQuartzJob`?

Comment: Thank you @JeffScottBrown, I am using following approach.

`JobDetail myJob = JobBuilder.newJob(MyJob.class).build()
        Trigger myTrigger = TriggerBuilder.newTrigger().
                withIdentity('someidentity').
                
        withSchedule(CronScheduleBuilder.cronSchedule('0 0/1 * 1/1 * ? *')).build()


        Scheduler scheduler = StdSchedulerFactory.getDefaultScheduler()
        scheduler.start()
        scheduler.scheduleJob(myJob, myTrigger)`

Answer (score 0):

you need to define a JobFactory.

```
package io.micronaut.quartz;

import io.micronaut.context.BeanContext;
import org.quartz.Job;
import org.quartz.JobDetail;
import org.quartz.Scheduler;
import org.quartz.SchedulerException;
import org.quartz.spi.JobFactory;
import org.quartz.spi.TriggerFiredBundle;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;

import javax.inject.Singleton;

@Singleton
public class MicronautJobFactory implements JobFactory {
    private final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(getClass());

    private final BeanContext beanContext;

    public MicronautJobFactory(BeanContext beanContext) {
        this.beanContext = beanContext;
    }

    @Override
    public Job newJob(TriggerFiredBundle bundle, Scheduler scheduler) throws SchedulerException {
        JobDetail jobDetail = bundle.getJobDetail();
        Class<? extends Job> jobClass = jobDetail.getJobClass();
        try {
            if (log.isDebugEnabled()) {
                log.debug(
                    "Producing instance of Job '" + jobDetail.getKey() +
                        "', class=" + jobClass.getName());
            }
            return beanContext.getBean(jobClass);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            SchedulerException se = new SchedulerException(
                "Problem instantiating class '"
                    + jobDetail.getJobClass().getName() + "'", e);
            throw se;
        }
    }
}
```

afterward when you define your scheduler you can will then have to add your factory builder to the quartz scheduler when you define it. This replaces the default builder that comes with Quartz.

All your jobs going forward will have to be defined using @Prototype or @Singleton annotation. By Default Quartz uses newInstance() which circumvents object defined by Micronaut, but this will defer the object building to Micronaut when the job is declared.

```
scheduler.setJobFactory(jobFactory);
```